# Org citations produced by src are not rendered in tabulated results

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, citation

For example to reproduce:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results table replace
"Prior research [cite:@paper] suggests that..."
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Prior research suggests that... |
```

The expected outcome:

```
#+RESULTS:
| Prior research [cite:@paper] suggests that... |
```

It seems that this does not depend on src language (I have tried with R - same issue).

When results are not tabulated org citations are rendered correctly in results.

*Org mode 9.5.3; GNU Emacs 28.2*

Comment: I tried to look into the cause of this behavior (which I can confirm), and it's pretty technical -- Org-babel calls `orgtbl-to-generic`, which in turn defines a custom derived export backend to format the table, but this export backend has no transcoder for citations, because those are taken care by Org-cite in a normal export process. It doesn't seem to be a lot of work to add the missing, trivial citation transcoder, so you might consider sending a corresponding feature request (or bug report...) to the Org mailing list.

Comment: Thank you for locating the issue @Simka! I have added a bug report to Org mailing list - https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2023-01/msg00808.html

Comment: I forgot that I already asked this question not so long ago. So this one actually duplicates [that one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71968/how-to-populate-org-table-with-org-citations-generated-by-r-scr).